# Rails: Trying to understand how to do better fragment caching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memcached, dalli, fragment-caching

In my app I am trying to incorporate better fragment caching.

Is it a best practice to do call fragments like this:

```
<% cache("user/#{current_user.id}/info") do %>
  <%= current_user.email %> information goes here
<% end %>
```

Comment: Yes it does, the fragment is uniq for each user, and the content is uniq for each user also, so nothing to worry about.

Comment: Thanks so much!! Can you put your comment in an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you are doing it right!

Why?
The cache fragment's key must reflect the "uniqueness" of the content:

- **Statement**: Your content is uniq *for each user*
- **Conclusion**: Your fragment's key must be different *for each user*
- **Usage**: using the user's id is the best choice since *every user id is uniq*!